# Make VS Code look declarations in "this" object?

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

```
{
    init: function () {
        this._someVar = 10;
    },
    _someVar: 0
}
```

Can VS Code discover object stored in *this*? Because now IntelliSense is blind on *this* objects and all features like autocomplete, suggestion popups cannot be used.